# IISNode define routes when app is running under IIS Application

Tags: node.js, iis, express, iisnode

I have a simple node.js application that has two endpoints

```
app.use('/', routes); 
app.use('/users' , users);
```

which I can access on the following urls: http://localhost:1234/ and http://localhost:1234/users

Now I create an IIS Application under the Default Web Site, pointed it to the nodejs application physical path and gives it an alias of "NodeApplication".

So the problem is that, right now my node.js routes definition must include the "NodeApplication" prefix, like this:

```
app.use('/NodeApplication', routes); 
app.use('/NodeApplication/users' , users);
```

My goal is to keep the first definition of routes in node.js application without any prefix and the IIS must redirect to the corresponding route.

For example: this url http://localhost/NodeApplication/users must triggers this route `app.use('/users', routes);`

Can anyone help me with this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Virtual Directory like you are doing within express but you will have to update your code to understand that you are running in a Virtual Directory.

I wrote a solution to this problem over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31482232/2980607).