# Running nodejs/MEAN app on IIS virtual directory setup

Tags: node.js, iis, mean-stack, mean.io, iisnode

I am running my MEAN app on windows. So far I was running the application on [Non-Sucking Service Manager](http://nssm.cc/) as a windows service. Now we need to enable windows authetication and we are planning to use IIS.

We are planning to use [IISNode](https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode) for this. So far I have read this [post](http://tomasz.janczuk.org/2011/08/hosting-express-nodejs-applications-in.html).

I installed the samples that comes with IISNode by running `setupsamples.bat` file.
running this file typically creates a virtual directory @ `C:\Program Files\iisnode\www`

I want to understand If I need to run my application, Do I always need to copy all the content under `C:\Program Files\iisnode\www` folder? Or I can create a new virtual directory and make it work ?

Answer (score 2):

I answered a similar question to this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15979904/iis-node-js-and-web-application-with-iisnode-not-configured-right/31482232#31482232)

IISNode allows you operate your Node.js app just like you would any other application in IIS. Just make sure you have IISNode, Node.js, and the [Url Re-write Module](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) installed on the environment as well as a Web.config for your app and you should be good to go. Without the URL Re-write module then you would have to go to http://host:port/app.js/ instead of http://host:port and IISNode takes advantage of it to accomplish this.

In that thread I have a template Web.config that I use with all my IISNode services/web apps. It will support all aspects of hosting in IIS, including hosting your app in a Virtual Directory. Just make sure that the main file for your app matches the main file referenced in the config file within the URL Re-writing section.

If you are using VS then I recommend downloading the [Node.js Tools for Visual Studio](https://nodejstools.codeplex.com/). It helps with creating the Web.config that you need for IISNode.