# how to deploy node.js app in iis virtual directory

Tags: node.js, iis, nuxt.js, iisnode

I found a way to deploy node app in iis route with iisnode and urlrewrite.
it worked very well.could any one help to this problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to serve NodeJS application from Windows Server Edition OS without using iisnode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62450658/how-to-serve-nodejs-application-from-windows-server-edition-os-without-using-iis)

Answer (score 0):

try to use the ng build command with href and use value of the virtual directory name.

below URL rewrite rule:

```
<rule name="StaticContent" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
                <action type="Rewrite" url="public/{R:0}" logRewrittenUrl="true"/>
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
                </conditions>
                <match url="*.*"/>
            </rule>

          
            <rule name="DynamicContent">
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="True"/>
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="server.js"/>
            </rule>
            <rule name="SocketIO" patternSyntax="ECMAScript">
                <match url="socket.io.+"/>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="server.js"/>
            </rule>
```

make sure iisnode module is installed.

[IIS, Node.js, and Web Application with IISNode not configured right with Virtual Directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15979904/iis-node-js-and-web-application-with-iisnode-not-configured-right-with-virtual/31482232#31482232)

[Running nodejs/MEAN app on IIS virtual directory setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31558394/running-nodejs-mean-app-on-iis-virtual-directory-setup)