# node + socket.io fails on 'listen' Azure deployment

Tags: node.js, azure, socket.io, iisnode

Nodejs server works like a champ locally. When deployed to Azure Web App, it fails with server error: 
isnode encountered an error when processing the request.

> HRESULT: 0x6d HTTP status: 500 HTTP subStatus: 1013 HTTP reason:
>   Internal Server Error You are receiving this HTTP 200 response because
>   system.webServer/iisnode/@devErrorsEnabled configuration setting is
>   'true'.
>   ...

No real info here, so turned to the logs... where I see:

> Fri Jul 24 2015 01:17:32 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time):
>   Unaught exception: TypeError: Object
>   \.\pipe\b9a229c1-7e20-4d2a-9f2d-fec75412cede has no method
>   'listeners'
>       at Server.attach (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\lib\server.js:358:26)
>       at Function.attach (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\lib\engine.io.js:124:10)
>       at Server.listen.Server.attach (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\socket.io\lib\index.js:226:21)
>       at new Server (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\socket.io\lib\index.js:51:17)
>       at Function.Server (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\socket.io\lib\index.js:39:41)
>       at Object. (D:\home\site\wwwroot\server.js:11:17)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)

Tracing that back, I think the line of interest is:

> at Object. (D:\home\site\wwwroot\server.js:11:17)

In the nodejs server code:

```
var socket = io.listen(process.env.port || 3000);
```

So I'm guessing the failure is possibly due to versioning or something? I can't seem to get any socket.io app to work on azure web deployment as cloud service or cloud app.

Anyone else?

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the rest of your code? The initialization of your `io` variable is important to understanding what went wrong.

Your code should look something like this when initializing if you are using Express 4

```
var app = require('express')();

var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
// Get the port that we should be listening on
server.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080);
```

Inside your config, when using IISNode you need to specify that you are using Socket.io by adding the following to your `<handlers>` element in your Web.config:

`<add name="iisnode-socket.io" path="server.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />`

Additionally, we need to let IISNode know how to direct our Socket.io requests by adding a new rewrite rule:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>        
    <rule name="SocketIO" patternSyntax="ECMAScript">
      <match url="socket.io.+" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="server.js"/>
    </rule>
  </rules>
<rewrite>
```

Also check and see if the socket.io package properly installed on your server instance.

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15979904/iis-node-js-and-web-application-with-iisnode-not-configured-right/31482232#31482232) an answer I wrote about getting IISNode working in IIS using Socket.io and Virtual Directory usage as well.