# IISNode issues running samples scripts

Tags: node.js, http, iis, iisnode

I'm probably not providing enough information here considering i'm a super noob when it comes to IIS, but here's what's going on.

So I followed [this tutorial](https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode) for installing IISNode by basically just doing the following lines:

```
1. Install iisnode for IIS 7.x/8.x: x86 or x64 - choose bitness matching your system
2. To set up samples, from the administrative command prompt call %programfiles%\iisnode\setupsamples.bat
3. Go to http://localhost/node
```

I installed the x64 version.

But when i try to go to `http://localhost/node`, this HTTP error appears:

[image]

Here's what my IIS manager looks like (not sure if this is helpful or not):

[image]

Any idea what could be going on here? Did I forget to download something? Am i not running something I should be? Any help appreciated.

Comment: [See my answer to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15979904/iis-node-js-and-web-application-with-iisnode-not-configured-right/31482232#31482232) for a full and complete tutorial on getting IISNode working with your node.js from scratch and implementing the apps as virtual directories as you have shown in your question. It also supplies a start Web.config and lists all dependencies needed like URL Re-Write for IIS

Comment: Quick question. How do you tell if you already have the URL re-write dependency. Because I think I have it already but I'm not sure.

Comment: It's listed in your IIS as module similar to headers

Comment: Do you have time to dm me for a little? Still having issues ):