# Run Node.js next to IIS

Tags: node.js, iis, iisnode

We are currently hosting a website on a server on port 80. Alongside that we would like to have a Node.js application running on the same port.

I already tried to use IISNode and run it as an application within the site, but without succes.

I keep getting the following error:
HRESULT: 0x2
HTTP status: 500
HTTP subStatus: 1001
HTTP reason: Internal Server Error

I was wondering wether anyone has accomplished the same with less effort?

Thanks

Comment: It cannot be done. Read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694144/can-two-applications-listen-to-the-same-port

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can two applications listen to the same port?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694144/can-two-applications-listen-to-the-same-port)

Comment: @RicardoC that is incorrect, you can. Simply add the Node.js Application as either a Virtual Application or a Virtual Directory under the primary application running on port 80

Comment: @peteb no you cannot. You are thinking on Virtual Application inside one IIS site. Virtual apps are run by a single application: IIS. At that point, a second application (node.js) cannot use the same port. Think "Applications" from the Operating System context; and not from the "webapp" point of view..

Comment: @RicardoC scratch my last comment, I think I'm misreading the question, I can see exactly how you're reading the question now and you are correct.

Comment: @peteb and I was about to say the same to you. At least on regards of IISNode. While what I said stands, the IISNode claims to be able to do this on some blogs, but I haven't been able to find any examples or related documentation.

Comment: @RicardoC I've written a number of [tutorials](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31482232/2980607) and [SO Docs](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/node.js/6003/using-iisnode-to-host-node-js-web-apps-in-iis/21004/using-an-iis-virtual-directory-or-nested-application-via-appsettings#t=20170202214207032725) for doing multiple Node.js sites running side-by-side within a single IIS Web Site using IISNode.