# How to set up ReactJS app on IIS properly?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, iis, iis-10

Watched through few topics on same question. None worked for me.
The thing is: 
I have ReactJS + Redux app designed from create-react-app. Actually it works but when app surfing starts with URL different from root is throws out 404.
Installed `iisnode` and tried out different rewrite rules recommended in web, but nothing works.
Last was this one:

```
    <rule name="Redirect HTTP to HTTPS">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent"/>
    </rule> -->

    <rule name="Redirect non-existent paths to root">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/initialLogin/*" ignoreCase="true" negate="true" />            
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="/" appendQueryString="false" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

The only thing I need is to send all incoming requests through root url with passing the rest of the address to it so that SPA could work properly. 
Hosting: AzureVM
IIS: v10

Edit: Another curious thing is thet `iisnode` can handle redirections with js files, but my application renders in `index.html` and when I tried to point `index.html` as handler it actually showed me a blank page.

Comment: I think another answer I've written on IISNode will help you, check it out [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31482232/2980607)

Comment: Thanks @peteb, partially it helped to find the solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This `web.config` works for me. Hope it will help someone else.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <!-- This part is responsible for URL rewrites -->
        <rewrite>
          <rules>
            <rule name="ReactJS Routes" stopProcessing="true">
              <match url=".*" />
              <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
              </conditions>
              <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
            </rule>
          </rules>
        </rewrite>
        <!-- This allows CORS for testing purposes -->
        <httpProtocol>
         <customHeaders>
           <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
         </customHeaders>
       </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: will it work in case of client side? if yes then what is `{REQUEST_FILENAME}` and `REQUEST_URI`

Comment: This works for me in 24 Mar, 2021, with IIS 10, and iisnode 0.2.26.0